# Display Test Failure Report in Circle CI using Karma

Tags: angularjs, junit, circleci

I'm running unit test on my angularjs source code using karma in Circle CI.
All is working fine, but I'm not able get a display of test failures. In test summary I get this warning which says,

> Set up your test runner to output in JUnit-style XML

I want to display the test failures tab as shown in the below picture [image]

Here is my circle.yml file :

```
test:
  override:
  - mkdir -p $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/junit/
  - karma start tests/my.conf.js --single-run --reporters junit
```

Here is my karma conf file where I have junit configurations :

```
junitReporter: {
  outputDir: '../$CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/',
  outputFile: 'test-results.xml'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

CircleCI will create a folder for your test results located at $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS

1. You do not need the mkdir part of your test, the directory is already there
2. The junitReporter is pointed to the wrong outputDirectory, change it to $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS

That should do it :)